# Ways of filling a 2xN board with tetris pieces

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there of filling a 2xN board with tetris pieces. I stumbled upon a similar problem and this seemed interesting to solve.

This is my progress:
Let S(n) be the number of ways of filling a 2xn board. Evidently, S(2)= 1 and S(4)=4. For n congruent to 2 mod 4, S(n)=2S(n-2)-1 as you can add 2x2 squares to any combination that fills a 2x4 board to either side but you have to subtract one as you would be counting twice to the one composed completely of 2x2 squares. I have been trying to determine S(n) for multiples of 4 but have been unsuccessful. I know I can fill it with ones that can fill 2x4 squares n times, but then for large numbers you can move the 2x2 squares around and these combinations make it hard to determine.

Comment: You can't fill a $2 \times 1$ board with Tetris pieces because they all have four squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall the Tetris pieces correctly, the only ones you can use here are the $2 \times 2$ square, the two $L$ pieces, one of each handedness and the straight.  If you use an L or a straight you have to  fill out a $2 \times 4$ rectangle with another of the same.  Let $A(n)$ be the number of ways to fill a $2 \times n$ board.  $A(n)$ is only defined for even $n$.  You can fill a $2 \times n$ board by making a $2 \times (n-2)$ and appending a square or by making a $2 \times (n-4)$ and appending one of the two configurations of $L$ pieces or a pair of straights.  The recurrence is then $$A(n)=A(n-2)+3A(n-4)$$ 
with starting conditions 
$$A(0)=1\\A(2)=1$$
The characteristic polynomial is $r^4=r^2+3$ with roots $r^2=\frac 12(1+\sqrt {13}),\frac 12(1-\sqrt {13})$ so the generic solution is $A(n)=a(\frac 12(1+\sqrt {13}))^{n/2}+b(\frac 12(1-\sqrt {13}))^{n/2}$ which give $a=\frac {1+2\sqrt{13}}4,b=\frac {3-2\sqrt{13}}4$ and the result is 
$$A(n)=\frac {1+2\sqrt{13}}4(\frac 12(1+\sqrt {13}))^{n/2}+\frac {3-2\sqrt{13}}4(\frac 12(1+\sqrt {13}))^{n/2}$$

Comment: How is A(0)=1 if it doesn't exist? Additionally, this does not work as A(6)=7.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't provide the correct answer for A(6)

Comment: Yes, $A(0)=1$ because there is one way to make a $2 \times 0$ rectangle-don't use any pieces. I had forgotten the straight piece, so the $2$ should be a $3$ as there are $3$ ways to make a $2 \times 4$ besides squares.  I will update.

Comment: can you explain how you went from the recursion to the polynomial?

Comment: It is the standard technique.  You imagine a solution of the form r^n and plug it into the recursion.  Each root of the polynomial gives a solution.  In this case the polynomial is quadratic in $r^2$ because we are only concerned with even $n$.  It would have been cleaner to solve the problem for $2 \times 2n$ rectangles.

Comment: Ok. But how do you arrive at r^4=r^2+3?

Comment: If $A(n)=r^n$, just plugging into the recurrence gives $r^n=r^{n-2}+3r^{n-4}$.  Now divide by $r^{n-4}$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation